# Error while creating OIM user with custom Role added in Lookup `Lookup.Users.Role`

Tags: lookup, oracle11gr2, oim

I have added few values in the OIM Lookup `Lookup.Users.Role` but all custom values are giving following error while creating or modifying users in OIM GUI.

```
IAM-3050056 : The specified value ABC for attribute Role is not one of the predefined values
```

Is there anything else that needs to be done in order to make the custom role values work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom UDF Lookup Field Type Doesn’t Work Properly After Adding Or Updating New Values untill you run `purgecache.sh`

Comment: If you added it from design console then it'll not need PurgeCache